# php cookie check accepted like facebook

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

i'm searching for the correct solution to check if the user accepts cookies or not without realoading the page. Facebook and other pages can check it without a page reload.
I can't find any solution like this.

Has anybody a good pratice to check if the user has cookies accepted?

Thank you very much.

Comment: i guess it will work with an ajax request. on the initial request the cookie is set, (or not) which means on the next request the server should can read the cookie. how to get an request without reloading the page ? with an ajax request.

Comment: @yes123 with only 12 points this isnt to hard :)

Comment: @Rufinus. The matter is not of 12 points the matter is of 9 questions that he has asked and none is accepted. It means this community is not upto his standards?

Comment: @yes123 true true i guess nobody will gets points of this user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you should write a cookie and then query another page (the one who actually checks if the cookies are enabled) through AJAX.

Comment: i need to know if the user accepts Cookies at the first page load! ajax could just call if the first page is loaded. But its too late! :-(

Comment: you need 2 requests to check for cookies, there is no other way.